# unit testing async-waterfall using mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, tdd, mocha.js

I am using Mocha as a testing framework for my node.js application.

I have an existing module that uses async-waterfall node module.I am trying to write a unit test case for it. I am unable to write a test case for the second function in the array. Any tips on how would I pass the result of one function to the next function in the array 
    `var async = require('async');`

```
module.exports.resetPassword = function(req,res,next){
 async.waterfall([
  function(done){
    var token = do something;
    done(err,token);
  },
   function(token,done){
       //do some stuff
     res.status(200).send('success');
   },
    ]function(err){ 
     //send failure response
     });
};
```

Comment: Hi, I don`t quite understand the issue. Are you trying to test the second waterfall method regardless of the first one? Can you change the method or is it given?

Comment: Hi, In the first function I am able to get some value to token. I need this token to be passed to the second function. I cannot change the method as it is an existing method

Comment: The issue that I am facing is that the control goes to the first function in the async waterfall, but after done(err,token) is called, the control does not enter the second function(token,done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the issue now.
In your test - you execute the line:

```
user.resetPassword(request,response,next);
```

And immediately after that - the line:

```
cryptoStub.restore();
```

The issue is - that async.waterfall will start the first method, but before it runs the second one, it will run the next line from the unit test, and therefore you don`t see the next method. Code that will solve it will be like:

```
user.resetPassword(request,response,function(err) {
    cryptoStub.restore();
    done();
});
```

Does it look better?

Comment: Hi Gilad, Thanks for the answer. Your solution worked :). Since I am new to node.js it took me a bit to understand. It actually worked for me without writing crytoStub,restore() inside the resetPassword. What I did not notice was that the call eventually went to the second function after the call to done() had executed. Coming from a .NET MS Test background I had expected the call to the second function to happen when the line user.resetPassword() gets executed and not after the control comes to the crypto.restore(). Need to look a bit more into asynchronous unit testing. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

My code is as follows. My issue is around writing a unit test case for this method. I am using mocha along with sinon for stubbing. The unit test that I have written is

**Unit Test**

```
  it("Should return an error if there is an error in retrieving the user details from the db",function(done)
{
    request={
        body:{
            email:'test@test.com'

        }
    };

    var expectedMessageFromCrypto = '12121212121';
    var cryptoStub = sinon.stub(crypto, "randomBytes",function(err,callback){
        callback(null,expectedMessageFromCrypto);
    });

    user.resetPassword(request,response,next);

    cryptoStub.restore();
    done();
});
});
```

**The resetPassword module**

```
methods.exports.resetPassword = function (req, res, next) {
var token = null;
async.waterfall([
    function (done) {
        crypto.randomBytes(16, function (err, buf) {
        if(err){
            return res.status(400);
        }
        else{
            token = buf.toString('hex');
        }
        done(err, token);
        });
    },
    function (token, done) {            
    var user = getUserInformation(req.body.email);
        sendEmail(user, done);
    }
], function (err) {
    if (err) {
        logger.error('error in sending confirmation mail');
        return next(err);
    }        
    res.status(200).send('success');
});
};
```

Comment: Your code actually look like it should work. I also tried it on my PC with slight changes and it got to the second method. maybe it gets stuck on getUserInformation? can you add console.log on various locations so you`ll know exactly where it gets stuck?

Comment: I added a console.log and got expected value. For me while I was debugging from my unit test code, the control did not enter getUserInformation. after crossing the function involving crypto, it just came out of the entire module. Am I missing something in my unit test? When I debug my prod code, it runs fine. Not sure if I am missing anything in my unit test case

Comment: I posted another answer