# How to Write unit tests for functions within Async.waterfall array Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am writing test cases using `Mocha`,

this is the structure of my code -

```
var async = require('async');

const uploadHandler = (req, res) => {
  async.waterfall([
    function testdata(callback){
      fetchdetails(callback, req, res);
    },

    function resignDocs(callback) {
      //do something
      console.log(req.body.name);
    }
  ]);
};

app.post('/uploadfile', uploadHandler);
exports.server = app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log('info', `Listening for incoming connections on port ${config.port}...`);
});
```

I am trying to write test cases for function `testdata` and function `resignDocs`,

I got the file using -

```
var app = require('../app')
```

(app.js is name of file with above code)

now `app.fetchdetails` doesn't let me access the function if I export it. And it needs `req` and `res` from `uploadHandler` too.

How to write unit tests for functions within `waterfall`.

Comment: Does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795226/unit-testing-async-waterfall-using-mocha ?

Comment: @rad No, unfortunately didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your functions before the `uploadHandler` and export them later on. By doing that you can get the full control over `resignDocs`, `uploadHandler` and even `uploadHandler` in your tests.

```js
var async = require('async');

function testdata(callback) {
    fetchdetails(callback, req, res);
}

function resignDocs(callback) {
    //do something
    console.log(req.body.name);
}

const uploadHandler = (req, res) => {
    async.waterfall([
        testdata,
        resignDocs
    ]);
};

app.post('/uploadfile', uploadHandler);

exports.server = app.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log('info', `Listening for incoming connections on port ${config.port}...`);
});

exports.testdata = testdata;
exports.resignDocs = resignDocs;
exports.uploadHandler = uploadHandler;
```

After you exported the functions like that you could for example leverage [sinon-express-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-express-mock) to mock req and res objects.

Comment: I thought of the same, then I realized I need `req` and `res` objects in these functions `testdata` and `resignDocs`, which is only available in `waterfall` function. 
And that's where I got stuck as in how to mock `req` or `res` to test `testdata` function.

Comment: @Darpan You could use something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-express-mock to mocke request and response.